# JavaScript regarding string and integer value

Tags: javascript

i need to help to learn this. Thanks in advance.

```
<label>Value 1</label> <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" /><br />

<script>

var num1 = document.getElementById("value1");
parseInt(num1.value) // this gives an integer when you key in an integer in the input box.

var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
parseInt(num1) // this gives NaN when you key in an integer in the input box. 

</script>
```

May i know why is there a difference between them? I thought that they are the same but it's not.

Comment: That would not happen; there's no difference, and if you're seeing a difference it's because you're not really supplying the same value, or some other error. It's impossible to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: Your example is ill-formed. Can you show us specifically what you have tested, and how you checked and parsed the given inputs separately?

Comment: Both give the same result (demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/aypdhzjq/). If the field has a number, both will show a number. If the field has anything but a number you'll get `NaN` (Not a Number)

Comment: parseInt() will not return NaN if the value to be parsed starts with a numeric value .. 3u8 will result in 3 e.g.

Answer (score 0):

From your new post (You posted as an answer, which is deleted now), You are trying to get the value from the input field before the values are inserted.

Move these lines to inside function `add`, so that value as assigned to variables only after clicking the button.

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
```

The function should be like

```
function add () {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  var sumup = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The total is " + sumup;
}
```

And the answer for your question is there is no difference between

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("value1");
parseInt(num1.value)
```

and

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
parseInt(num1)
```

Check the snippet below

```html
<form action="" name="add1">
  <label>Value 1</label>
  <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" />
  <br />
  <label>Value 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <br />
  <button type="button" id="addup">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  document.getElementById("addup").addEventListener("click", add);

  function add() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
    var sumup = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The total is " + sumup;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Both examples seem equivalent, something else is wrong. Maybe you are overwriting `num1` variable? Try this:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("value1");
parseInt(num1.value) // this gives an integer when you key in an integer in the input box.

var num2 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
parseInt(num2) // this gives NaN when you key in an integer in the input box.
```

Comment: This is a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Also note that even if `num1` was being overwritten by the second fetch, that wouldn't explain the different results on each case.
Your intervention in one of my other answers suggests that you are upset about my response, and I'm sorry if you feel that way. But let's be honest, the only right attitude here is to wait for the question to be either improved or closed.